# ScrollMagic offset on different window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, scrollmagic, gasp

I am using ScrollMagic to get some animations on scroll. The problem is that I need to use offset so that the animation triggers on some point of scroll but it totally depends on the window height.

So in the example i have provided

```
https://jsfiddle.net/5tvrnfkx/12/
```

you can see the box coming out on scroll. https://tppr.me/RpkVa

Notice the window height https://tppr.me/hoyhs try resizing the height or preview panel and run.

So in `426px` window height, it works perfectly. starts the page with no box and animates on scroll.

Try increasing the height and check https://tppr.me/sYJ5a, the box appears at the start. similarly, if you reduce the height, the box appears only after few scroll.

So I was wondering if there's any way to make the offset value dynamic so in any window height, the animation starts at the exact same point of scroll of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, instead of using `offset`, you can use `triggerHook` and set it to `0` (or very close to it).

Like this:

```
jQuery(function() {

  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    var tween = TweenMax.to("#boxAnim", 1, {className: "+=animate"});
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger", duration: 300, triggerHook: 0})
            .setTween(tween)
            .addTo(controller);


  var height = $(window).outerHeight();

  $('.height').append(height);
});
```

Comment: that worked, thank you. could you briefly explain how this is working? what the difference using `offset` and `triggerhook` ?

Comment: Sure. Briefly, `offset` is based on pixels and `triggerHook` is relative - number 0 to 1. They're use `triggerElement` as reference. In general you may prefer to use `triggerHook` instead of `offset`. I found this if you want to know more: https://ihatetomatoes.net/visual-guide-scrollmagic (Probably explains a lot better than me).

Comment: do you know if there's any way to disable it for wider screen? I tried something like this `$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  if (winWidth >= 1680) {
   scene.destroy();
  } else {
   scene.refresh();
  }
 }).resize();` below the code but it won't work.

Comment: Yes, but we need some more changes. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/02ng716z/. Quick explanation: var `scene` now is declared globally. Created `function initScrollMagic()`. Then when resize, if `winWidth>= 1680` && `scene` is not undefined, it'll destroy `scene` (`true` to reset `tween`) and set scene to `undefined`. The opposite, if `winWidth < 1680` and `scene` is undefined, it will call `initScrollMagic` to create it again.

Comment: that helped but now i figured out exactly what my problem was. It's when we have more that 1 element to animate. like in real time, i have lot of animation to be handled and this is how i have used it https://jsfiddle.net/z4srp2bq/3/ so what happens is, it works great on page refresh but on resize the page jumps. should i be using `$(each)` statement?

Comment: with some workaround, i used unique variable for all scene and tween like this https://jsfiddle.net/z4srp2bq/5/ and it worked. would this be a good call though?

Comment: That's cool. I believe it can be simplified because it has details that repeat. At the moment I don't know exactly how.